# How to create an inline scope with return value in c++?

Tags: c++, lambda, scope

I have a larger `if` expression let's say of the kind

```
if (a && (c(b.getObject()) || d(b.getObject()))
{
    ...
}
```

is there a way to declare `b.getObject()` as local reference only if `a` is `true`?
I'm looking for a kind of lambda function perhaps like this:

```
if (a && { Object & o(b.getObject()); return (c(o) || d(o))} )
{
    ...
}
```

but this obviously doesn't work. 
Of course I could nest it in another `if` block, but is there a more "local" way to do it?

edit:
One argument against nested `if`blocks is that they do not allow one combined `else` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a function that does the two checks, and call it so you only evaluate `b.getObject()` once.

```
auto e = [](const Object& o) { return c(o) || d(o); };
if (a && e(b.getObject()))
{
    ...
}
```

Prior to C++11 you would have to write `e` as a function at namespace scope, or as a variable of a local class type with an `operator()`.

Also, G++ has a non-standard ["statement expression"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension that allows what you want, with slightly different syntax:

```
if (a && ({ const Object& o = b.getObject(); c(o) || d(o); }))
{
  ...
}
```

However, I think generally a nested `if` is much cleaner and easier to read than either of these alternatives.

Comment: The g++ non-standard version seems to be the thing I looked for. But I see how the nested if is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this, but it works...

```
Object x;

if (a && (x = b.getObject(), c(x) || d(x)))
{
}
```

Comment: It works if `Object` is DefaultConstructible and CopyAssignable and if you are happy to copy it not use a reference.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The DefaultConstructible constraint could be worked around by using a pointer. You're right about CopyAssignable. As I said, "please don't do this." ;-) (Edit: I guess the pointer thing wouldn't actually help that either, nevermind.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a lambda for that:

```
if (a && [&b](){ const Object& o = b.getObject(); return c(o) || d(o); }() ) {
    ...
}
```

but declaring the function outside the condition seems cleaner.